# How to get the first column after Group by in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get the #1 item after Group by in SQL?

Here is my code.

```
          SELECT BUSEO, COUNT(BUSEO)
          FROM TBLINSA
          GROUP BY BUSEO
          ORDER BY COUNT(BUSEO) DESC
```

The result is 7 rows.

I am curious about how to select and import only the first column from among them.

Comment: Do you mean to return only the first ROW while returning the first COLUMN ?

Answer (score 2):

The first **column**? Omit `count` from `select` statement:

```
SELECT BUSEO
FROM TBLINSA
GROUP BY BUSEO
ORDER BY COUNT(BUSEO) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your DB version;

For `12c+` use

```
SELECT buseo
  FROM
  (
   SELECT buseo, COUNT(buseo) AS cnt_buseo
     FROM tblinsa
    GROUP BY buseo
    ORDER BY cnt_buseo DESC
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
   )
```

where repeating `COUNT(buseo)` within the `ORDER BY` list is redundant, eg. using an alias is possible.

Prior to `12c` use

```
SELECT buseo
  FROM
  (
    SELECT buseo, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(buseo) DESC) AS rn 
      FROM tblinsa
     GROUP BY buseo
  ) 
 WHERE rn = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6f03f14346b62d0cc40acbb039c7aa05)</kbd>

Comment: For old versions it is also possible with just [rownum](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) after subquery, which allows to use convenient `order by <position>` and make the query text slightly simpler.

Comment: Hi @astentx . Unfortunately `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn is problematic. If an `ORDER BY` clause follows `ROWNUM` in the same query, then the rows will be reordered by the `ORDER BY` clause. The results can vary depending on the way the rows are accessed. For each row returned by a query, the `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn returns a number indicating the order in which Oracle selects the row from a table